# What would be a good solution to compare two files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs

I am trying to build a simple auto-grader that checks for two javascript matching files.

This is an example of a possible exercise:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8000,  () => {
console.log('Node server is running..');
});
```

This is the solution of the above exercise:

```
var http = require('http');
var dt = require('./myfirstmodule');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write("The date and time are currently: " + dt.myDateTime());
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8000,  () => {
console.log('Node server is running..');
});
```

Do you know a good solution in Node to check if the exercise file matches the solution? Matching the files exactly might not be a good idea as there could be white spaces in between and still be a valid solution.

Thanks in advance.

Andrea

Comment: Checking the code itself instead of the produced result is not a "*simple* auto-grader". You can write multiple programs with different code, and different AST-s, that do the same thing. Test functionality instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each file contents using [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) then use the package [string similarity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity) to compare between them.

Install string similarity:

```
npm install string-similarity --save
```

Then in your code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stringSimilarity = require('string-similarity');

let exercise = fs.readFileSync('path/to/file/exercise.js');
let solution = fs.readFileSync('path/to/file/solution.js');

var similarity = stringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings(exercise, solution);
console.log(similarity); //Returns a fraction between 0 and 1
```